# How to compile a C program that uses stdlib.h?

Tags: compiling

For `math.h` I use `-lm` , what do I use for `stdlib.h`? And what about `time.h`?

Comment: No need to use any special flag.

Comment: you should've tried compiling and see what happens, before asking a question try something first and when it fails, come and ask a question.

Comment: @Valerio - The file stdlib.h is like the file stdio.h - there is no special flag necessary for this - std is abbreviation for standard and means, that file belongs to main construct of gcc. You might look here in this online book ... http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html

Comment: @julekgwa you're assuming OP haven't tried compiling yet, plus compilers have tons of options. Don't use accusatory tone, be nice. Everyone starts out as a noob

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy If he tried compiling the code, he wouldn't have asked the question, by asking this question he clearly hasn't tried compiling the code. Sorry if I'm being rude.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add anything. Only the math.h needs -lm.